# pyautogui not being recognized in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, pyautogui

When I type `import pyautogui` it says the module is not recognized. I have pip installed it in the correct version of python. Anyone knows why?

Comment: You have probably installed the module in the wrong location, as VS uses a virtual environment.

Comment: What [Python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) do you use in VS Code? (Global environment or virtual environment or conda environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I installed the module "pyautogui" using pip, the terminal still showed that the module could not be found. (Take the global python environment as an example.)

We can use the command "`pip show pyautogui`" to check where the module is installed:

[image]

In this location we can see that the file name of the module is "pyautogui", and we use "PyAutoGUI" in the code.

[image]

Solution: Therefore, we can change the file name of the module to "`PyAutoGUI`", or use the code "`import pyautogui`". However, since the "PyAutoGUI_pyautogui_win.py" file uses "import pyautogui", it is recommended that you change the code to "import pyautogui". (And all lowercase is used in the ["pyautogui" official document](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/).)

Run:

[image]